# Caliper benchmark fails due to JIT compilation

Tags: java, microbenchmark, caliper

I got a Caliper benchmark which looks like this:

```
public Course timeCourseCreation( int i ) {

  return createCourse( i );
}

public Course createCourse( int t ) {

  Course course = new Course();

  for ( int i = 0 + t; i < this.students + t; i++ ) {
    Student student = new Student();
    student.setAge( ( int ) ( 100 * Math.random() ) + t );
    student.setName( UUID.randomUUID().toString() );
    course.getStudents().add( student );
  }

  for ( int i = 0 + t; i < this.courses + t; i++ ) {
    Topic topic = new Topic();
    topic.setDescription( UUID.randomUUID().toString() );
    topic.setDifficulty( ( int ) ( 10 * Math.random() ) + t );
    topic.setName( UUID.randomUUID().toString() );
    topic.setRating( ( int ) ( 10 * Math.random() ) + t );
    course.getTopics().add( topic );
  }

  return course;
}
```

So, I have a method which creates a data structure (`createCourse(...)`) and I want to measure how long it takes to create this structure.

However, when I run the benchmark, I get the following exception:

```
Failed to execute java -cp C:\Users\tuhrig\workspace\XmlVsJson\target\classes;C:\Users\tuhrig\.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.2.11\jaxb-api-2.2.11.jar;C:\Users\tuhrig\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.2.4\gson-2.2.4.jar;C:\Users\tuhrig\.m2\repository\com\google\caliper\caliper\0.5-rc1\caliper-0.5-rc1.jar;C:\Users\tuhrig\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\1.3.9\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:\Users\tuhrig\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\11.0.1\guava-11.0.1.jar;C:\Users\tuhrig\.m2\repository\com\google\code\java-allocation-instrumenter\java-allocation-instrumenter\2.0\java-allocation-instrumenter-2.0.jar;C:\Users\tuhrig\.m2\repository\asm\asm\3.3.1\asm-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\tuhrig\.m2\repository\asm\asm-analysis\3.3.1\asm-analysis-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\tuhrig\.m2\repository\asm\asm-commons\3.3.1\asm-commons-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\tuhrig\.m2\repository\asm\asm-tree\3.3.1\asm-tree-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\tuhrig\.m2\repository\asm\asm-util\3.3.1\asm-util-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\tuhrig\.m2\repository\asm\asm-xml\3.3.1\asm-xml-3.3.1.jar com.google.caliper.InProcessRunner --warmupMillis 3000 --runMillis 1000 --measurementType TIME --marker //ZxJ/ -Dbenchmark=CourseCreation de.tuhrig.Benchmark
starting Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=CourseCreation}
[caliper] [starting warmup]
[caliper] [starting measured section]
[caliper] [done measured section]
[caliper] [starting measured section]
...
Error: Doing 2x as much work didn't take 2x as much time! Is the JIT optimizing away the body of your benchmark?
...
An exception was thrown from the benchmark code.
com.google.caliper.ConfigurationException: Failed to execute java -cp C:\Users\tuhrig\workspace\XmlVsJson\target\classes;C:\Users\tuhrig\.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.2.11\jaxb-api-2.2.11.jar;C:\Users\tuhrig\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.2.4\gson-2.2.4.jar;C:\Users\tuhrig\.m2\repository\com\google\caliper\caliper\0.5-rc1\caliper-0.5-rc1.jar;C:\Users\tuhrig\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\1.3.9\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:\Users\tuhrig\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\11.0.1\guava-11.0.1.jar;C:\Users\tuhrig\.m2\repository\com\google\code\java-allocation-instrumenter\java-allocation-instrumenter\2.0\java-allocation-instrumenter-2.0.jar;C:\Users\tuhrig\.m2\repository\asm\asm\3.3.1\asm-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\tuhrig\.m2\repository\asm\asm-analysis\3.3.1\asm-analysis-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\tuhrig\.m2\repository\asm\asm-commons\3.3.1\asm-commons-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\tuhrig\.m2\repository\asm\asm-tree\3.3.1\asm-tree-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\tuhrig\.m2\repository\asm\asm-util\3.3.1\asm-util-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\tuhrig\.m2\repository\asm\asm-xml\3.3.1\asm-xml-3.3.1.jar com.google.caliper.InProcessRunner --warmupMillis 3000 --runMillis 1000 --measurementType TIME --marker //ZxJ/ -Dbenchmark=CourseCreation de.tuhrig.Benchmark
    at com.google.caliper.Runner.measure(Runner.java:309)
    at com.google.caliper.Runner.runScenario(Runner.java:229)
    at com.google.caliper.Runner.runOutOfProcess(Runner.java:378)
    at com.google.caliper.Runner.run(Runner.java:97)
    at com.google.caliper.Runner.main(Runner.java:423)
    at de.tuhrig.CaliperRunner.main(CaliperRunner.java:22)
```

The exception tells me that the benchmark fails because of JIT compilation. **So, how can I prevent the JIT compilation here?**

I already tried to initialize the data structure with random values (as you can see in the code), I tried to return a value in my test (as you can see in the code) and I tried to use the `course` object, e.g. to call `course.getSize()` on it. But nothing works.

Answer (score 7):

JIT is known to mess with your code in horrible ways, making all the measurements absolutely unreliable. People struggle a lot, trying to make things at least somewhat right, but end up writing things like [JMH](http://shipilev.net/talks/devoxx-Nov2013-benchmarking.pdf). Which is a great tool that helps measure performance and actually get results that make sense. It even enables you to [avoid dead code elimination](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/d43d5b30f721/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_08_DeadCode.java) and has a great number of [samples](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/d43d5b30f721/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples), looking at which would definitely help you solve your problem...

But this is the wrong way. It is usually kept a secret, but since you have figured out the right approach on your own, I will tell you. You can disable the JIT by using the [`-Xint` option](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html). There. No need to thank me.

Comment: I will try the `-Xint` option and take a look at JMH. Thanks.

Comment: @ThomasUhrig, please do not use `-Xint`. Here's how I read your post:
I needed to measure the speed of wind. To do so, I decided to take a sniper rifle and see how far bullets landed from the center of the target.
Except that I took a 17th century musket, which fired into my foot while I was trying to use it. That has happened because my finger pulled the trigger.
How do I cut the finger off so this doesn't happen again?

Comment: Of course I will try it! Look, I am not interested in how fast my code actually is. It doesn't matter for me if it is 10 ms, 20 ms or 100 ms fast. I just want to compare two different algorithms and know which one is faster compared to the other. Maybe the `-Xint` option is not to cut of my finger, but to use the lock at my rifle to don't shoot me.

Comment: @ThomasUhrig, I'd say that the relative performance of two different algorithms in interpretation mode and in fully JIT-compiled mode can vary awfully. I do not have a demonstration at hand, but hopefully I will get one.

Answer (score 3):

You can't benchmark stuff that depends on UUID generation. Getting random information from most OS'es depends on the OS state, the state of the random pool, etc.
I found out that this invokes unreliable behaviour.

Get rid of that to start with.

Comment: Thanks. I will rewrite my code without UUID and `Math.random()`. I thought it was a good idea to keep the POJOs slightly different, since I am using them in later benchmarks.

Answer (score 0):

You Benchmark is not very usefull: you test mostly the speed of Math.random and UUID. Also it "just" allocates a PoJo (as it seems), what results would you expect from that, other that it might or might not be bound by the GC.

JIT is not your problem, as you want your code to be speed up. I am not sure where the problem is, as you return the created objects the JIT may not suppress the code (unless Caliper does not work reliable).

I suspect that Math random or the GC causes the erratic results. You could try to use JMH, but it wont make the measurement more useful.

Comment: I know that this one is not very useful, but it is just an example. My actual benchmarks measure different algorithms on a data structure which looks similar to the `course > student & topic` example from above. However, my benchmarks keep failing and I discovered that it is due to the creation of the initial data structure, so I broke it down to this example. But you are right, Math.random and UUID are the most expensive parts here.